# summary_table in qwraps2 with group_by in R

Tags: r, dplyr, qwraps2

I am trying out the qwraps2 package and some of its functions. In particular I am interested in the summary_table tool for output.
I am using the iris data set for practice, but I noticed something strange when using group_by in the summary_table:

```
library(datasets)
data("iris")
options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown")
our_summary1 <-
  list("Sepal Length" =
       list("min" = ~ min(iris$Sepal.Length),
            "max" = ~ max(iris$Sepal.Length),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(iris$Sepal.Length)),
       "Sepal Width" =
       list("min" = ~ min(iris$Sepal.Width),
            "median" = ~ median(iris$Sepal.Width),
            "max" = ~ max(iris$Sepal.Width),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(iris$Sepal.Width)),
       "Petal Length" =
       list("min" = ~ min(iris$Petal.Length),
            "max" = ~ max(iris$Petal.Length),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(iris$Sepal.Length)),
       "Petal Width" =
       list("min" = ~ min(iris$Petal.Width),
            "max" = ~ max(iris$Petal.Width),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(iris$Petal.Width)),
        "Species" =
       list("Setosa" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(iris$Species == "setosa"),
            "Versicolor"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(iris$Species == "versicolor"),
            "Virginica"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(iris$Species == "virginica"))
       )

bytype <- qwraps2::summary_table(dplyr::group_by(iris,Species),our_summary1)
bytype
```

The output i get is:
[output from the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22nxc.png)

This doesnt make sense, it says that the statistics on different variables across different flower species are the same, which they are not. I cross checked this by doing:

```
aggregate(iris[1:4], list(iris$Species), mean)
```

which shows that for example the mean of the different variables varies across species.

Why is `dplyr::group_by` not doing what it should?

i posted the output as best I could, sorry and thank you for the comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the `group_by` call does not appear to do anything is because the
data pronoun `.data` is not being used in the summary definition. As
written, the summary table is constructed based on the whole `iris` data set,
regardless of any grouping or subsetting. The `.data` pronoun is needed so
that the the `tidyverse` tools behind `summary_table` use the correct
scoping.

```r
library(datasets)
library(qwraps2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

data("iris")
options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown")

our_summary1 <-
  list("Sepal Length" =
       list("min" = ~ min(.data$Sepal.Length),
            "max" = ~ max(.data$Sepal.Length),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$Sepal.Length)),
       "Sepal Width" =
       list("min" = ~ min(.data$Sepal.Width),
            "median" = ~ median(.data$Sepal.Width),
            "max" = ~ max(.data$Sepal.Width),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$Sepal.Width)),
       "Petal Length" =
       list("min" = ~ min(.data$Petal.Length),
            "max" = ~ max(.data$Petal.Length),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$Sepal.Length)),
       "Petal Width" =
       list("min" = ~ min(.data$Petal.Width),
            "max" = ~ max(.data$Petal.Width),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$Petal.Width)),
        "Species" =
       list("Setosa" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(.data$Species == "setosa"),
            "Versicolor"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(.data$Species == "versicolor"),
            "Virginica"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(.data$Species == "virginica"))
       )


bytype <- qwraps2::summary_table(dplyr::group_by(iris,Species),our_summary1)
bytype
#> 
#> 
#> |                        |Species: setosa (N = 50) |Species: versicolor (N = 50) |Species: virginica (N = 50) |
#> |:-----------------------|:------------------------|:----------------------------|:---------------------------|
#> |**Sepal Length**        |&nbsp;&nbsp;             |&nbsp;&nbsp;                 |&nbsp;&nbsp;                |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; min        |4.3                      |4.9                          |4.9                         |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; max        |5.8                      |7.0                          |7.9                         |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; mean (sd)  |5.01 &plusmn; 0.35       |5.94 &plusmn; 0.52           |6.59 &plusmn; 0.64          |
#> |**Sepal Width**         |&nbsp;&nbsp;             |&nbsp;&nbsp;                 |&nbsp;&nbsp;                |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; min        |2.3                      |2.0                          |2.2                         |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; median     |3.4                      |2.8                          |3.0                         |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; max        |4.4                      |3.4                          |3.8                         |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; mean (sd)  |3.43 &plusmn; 0.38       |2.77 &plusmn; 0.31           |2.97 &plusmn; 0.32          |
#> |**Petal Length**        |&nbsp;&nbsp;             |&nbsp;&nbsp;                 |&nbsp;&nbsp;                |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; min        |1.0                      |3.0                          |4.5                         |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; max        |1.9                      |5.1                          |6.9                         |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; mean (sd)  |5.01 &plusmn; 0.35       |5.94 &plusmn; 0.52           |6.59 &plusmn; 0.64          |
#> |**Petal Width**         |&nbsp;&nbsp;             |&nbsp;&nbsp;                 |&nbsp;&nbsp;                |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; min        |0.1                      |1.0                          |1.4                         |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; max        |0.6                      |1.8                          |2.5                         |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; mean (sd)  |0.25 &plusmn; 0.11       |1.33 &plusmn; 0.20           |2.03 &plusmn; 0.27          |
#> |**Species**             |&nbsp;&nbsp;             |&nbsp;&nbsp;                 |&nbsp;&nbsp;                |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Setosa     |50 (100)                 |0 (0)                        |0 (0)                       |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Versicolor |0 (0)                    |50 (100)                     |0 (0)                       |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Virginica  |0 (0)                    |0 (0)                        |50 (100)                    |
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using .data$ instead of iris$ when declaring the variables. I had the same problem and this fixed it.